# Facebook Login in Website - How to Cross Validate

Tags: facebook, authentication

How does my website know when users are logging in with their facebook account for the first time - so that if they arent registered with me i can then create the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think to know the first time user logs in with facebook would have to be controlled on your side.

You'll want to build some sort of logic to store the user's FB info like FB UID and email perhaps, in your DB when they login through FB. Additionally, you'll want to do a lookup for the user's UID and email in your DB on each time the user logs in through FB.

You might also want to consider if the user ever decides to "disconnect" their account from FB / revoke access to your app through FB. In this case, you'll want to remove their UID and email from the DB since they've chosen to revoke access.

If they decide to come back, then treat them as a new user and repeat the steps above.

A majority of your code will be checking the response from `FB.getLoginStatus` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback...will give a feedback once done

Comment: Personally I would consider those accounts as to separate things - Facebook user "creates" a user in your web APP in your DB - I would not delete him/her from DB just for denying permissions for your app for a while (because thats what deleting app from fb account is) - however you should then give him an option to delete account on your website :) Otherwise I agree with @Sam Tsai

Answer (score 0):

You can experiment with FB.Event.Subscribe and 'auth.authResponseChange'.
Check the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/)